# Can't find component from bean

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, javabeans

I wonder why I can't find a component from my backing bean, the code for the bean does:

```
UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("form_01:meterDialog:lazyGrid");
component.toString();
```

and the jsf is:

```
<h:form id="form_01">
    <p:dialog id="meterDialog" header="Meters" widgetVar="meter_data"
    minimizable="true" maximizable="true" draggable="true"
    resizable="true" height="auto" width="auto" onShow="enableForm()">

        <p:remoteCommand id="cmd" name="enableForm" update="lazyGrid">
        <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{true}"
            target="#{chartBean.formEnable}" />
        </p:remoteCommand>

        <p:panelGrid id="lazyGrid" rendered="true">
        </p:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

the problem is that it cant find **lazyGrid**, it can find the **meterDialog** with:

```
viewRoot.findComponent("form_01:meterDialog");
```

with no problems, but not the components **lazyGrid** or **cmd**

Comment: There are no components with the `id="lazyGrid"` in your code..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your form is having attribute prependId="false" then you can find with the actual component id.

Since you don't have that attribute set you have to refer from the UIViewRoot. if p:dialog is a naming container(i'm not sure) then you have to refer lazyGrid as "form_01:meterDialog:lazyGrid" else "form_01:lazyGrid".

Here is the link which will give you a more insight
[How to find out client ID of component for ajax update/render? Cannot find component with expression "foo" referenced from "bar"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634156/how-to-reference-components-in-jsf-ajax-cannot-find-component-with-identifier)

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should set `lazyGrid` as the panelGrid id?
And close the quotes in `UIComponent component = viewRoot.findComponent("form_01:meterDialog:lazyGrid");` !

Comment: was a typo that the " was lost

Comment: Try just: `viewRoot.findComponent("form_01:lazyGrid");`